# How to set the page title for controller actions?

Tags: php, controller, yii

I want to have different title (in head) for each Controller and action. 
How to do this from the controller?

Comment: I dont know why, but $this->pageTitle won't work..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Your Controller

```
    class SiteController {
        public function actionIndex() {
            $this->pageTitle = 'Home page';
            //...
        }

        //..
    }
```

### Layout file

```
    <title><?php echo $this->pageTitle; ?></title>
```

Maybe you forgot to add reference in your html?

Comment: +1 one minor note, make sure you have the $pageTitle variable defined in the parent controller class, I think it's there by default, but doesn't hurt to check it.

Comment: But you need to write the same line in each action of your controller by this way, which is not better solution. Try out my way, I hope that is the best way.

Comment: @onkarjanwa you right about that its need to be written in every page but i usualy writing for each controller separated title. But default pageTitle is written in my extended class **class Controller extends CController** in **beforeAction** as **$this->pageTitle = 'My Default Title';**. Maybe init also is good place, i dont know.

Comment: @briiC.lv yes you can use init function suggested by me for each controller which extends class Controller, it will overwritten $this->pageTitle variable.

Answer (score 8):

### If you want to have a different title in each action

Then simply set the value of [`CController.pageTitle`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#pageTitle-detail) inside your action:

```
class MyController extends CController {
    public function actionIndex() {
        $this->pageTitle = "my title";
        // other code here
    }
}
```

### If you want to share a specific title between multiple actions

One way would be to simply follow the above approach, possibly by using a class constant as the page title:

```
class MyController extends CController {
    const SHARED_TITLE = "my title";

    public function actionIndex() {
        $this->pageTitle = self::SHARED_TITLE;
        // other code here
    }

    public function actionFoo() {
        $this->pageTitle = self::SHARED_TITLE;
        // other code here
    }
}
```

However, this requires you to visit each action separately whenever you want to include or exclude it from the "title sharing" scheme. A solution that does not have this drawback is to use a [filter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller#filter). For example:

```
class MyController extends CController {
    public function filters() {
        // set the title when running methods index and foo
        return array('setPageTitle + index, foo');

        // alternatively: set the title when running any method except foo
        return array('setPageTitle - foo');
    }

    public function filterSetPageTitle($filterChain) {
        $filterChain->controller->pageTitle = "my title";
        $filterChain->run();
    }

    public function actionIndex() {
        // $this->pageTitle is now set automatically!
    }

    public function actionFoo() {
        // $this->pageTitle is now set automatically!
    }
}
```

### If you want to have the same title across all actions

This is obvious, but I mention it for completeness:

```
class MyController extends CController {
    public $pageTitle = "my title";

    public function actionIndex() {
        // $this->pageTitle is already set
    }

    public function actionFoo() {
        // $this->pageTitle is already set
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function init or before action or run which call before the actual action call. So In that function you can set the public pageTitle variable for the controller.

Use Like this:

```
public function init()
{
  parent::init();
  $this->pageTitle = "My Page Title";
}
```

Comment: Somehow, adding $this->pageTitle='new Title' or $this->setPageTitle('newTitle'); doesn't change the Title.
Any other way?

Comment: I have tested my code. I think you are overwriting the pageTitle variable in any view or layout file. please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Yon can give like this:-

```
$this->set("title", "Enrollment page");
```

and use this $title in ur ctp files by giving different name or title..

try this..

Comment: what do you mean by ctp files?

Answer (score 0):

In the VIEW page (index.php, view.php, create.php etc)

```
$this->setPageTitle('custom page title');
```